# Cannot upload csv into mysql

Tags: mysql, windows, load-data-infile

could someone tell me what am i doing wrong?

that's what I type in MySQL shell

```
-> LOAD DATA INFILE C:\ProgramData\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\Uploads\aavoc.csv
                               -> INTO TABLE googlecoursera.table1
                               -> FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
                               -> ENCLOSED BY '"'
                               -> LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n'
                               -> IGNORE 1 LINES;
```

and that's what I get

> ERROR: Unknown command '\P'
>  ERROR: Unknown command '\M'
>  ERROR:
> Unknown command '\M'
>  ERROR: Unknown command '\U'
>  ERROR:
> Unknown command '\a'
>  ERROR: 1064 (42000): You have an error in
> your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL
> server version for the right syntax to use near 'C:rogramDataySQLySQL
> Server 8.0ploadsavoc.csv
>  LOAD DATA INFILE C:rogramDataySQLy' at
> line 1

Comment: C:\ProgramData\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\Uploads\aavoc.csv - should be enclosed in single quotes

Comment: Missing quotes for the file name?

Answer (score 0):

It might be / instead of \ for ':\ProgramData\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\Uploads\aavoc.csv'. Try using '/'

Comment: Did as you said. Did not solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Put quotes around the file name.

```
LOAD DATA INFILE 'C:\ProgramData\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\Uploads\aavoc.csv'
                           INTO TABLE googlecoursera.table1
                           FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
                           ENCLOSED BY '"'
                           LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n'
                           IGNORE 1 LINES;
```

Comment: i did as you said and got this error.

ERROR: 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''C:\ProgramData\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\Uploads\aavoc.csv'

Comment: Looks like you have a double quote at the beginning and a single quote at the end. Should be a single quote at both places.